# convert s1 to palindrome with s2 as its substring

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, substring, palindrome

https://discuss.codechef.com/t/given-string-s1-and-s2-how-to-convert-given-string-s1-with-minimum-changes-to-palindrome-which-includes-s2-as-substring/69769

can some one help me understand this code please

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
```

using namespace std;

int main(){

```
string s1,s2;
cin>>s1>>s2;
int l1=s1.length(),l2=s2.length();
int ans=INT_MAX;
if(l2>l1){

    cout<<-1<<endl; // not possible
    return 0;
}
for(int i=0 ; i<l1-l2+1 ; i++){

    string temp=s1.substr(0,i)+s2+s1.substr(i+l2); // place s2 in all possible positions in s1
    int cost=0;
    // calculate cost to place s2
    for(int j=i ; j<i+l2 ; j++){

        if(s1[j]!=temp[j])
            cost++;
    }
    int z=0;
    // find the cost to convert new string to palindrome
```

**Can someone explain below code please**

```
    for(int j=0 ; j<ceil(l1/2.0) ; j++){

        if((j<i || j>=i+l2) && temp[j]!=temp[l1-j-1]) //(explain please) if s2 is in the first half of new string
            cost++;
        else if(temp[j]!=temp[l1-j-1] && (l1-j-1<i || l1-j-1>=i+l2)) // (explain please)if s2 is in the second half of new string
            cost++;
        else if(temp[j]!=temp[l1-j-1]){ // if s2 is in both halves

            z=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(z==0)
        ans=min(ans,cost);
}
if(ans==INT_MAX)
    cout<<-1<<endl;
else
    cout<<ans<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: this code is incomplete. Which part specifically dont you understand?

Comment: indeed... the code references vars i, l1, cost, and z as well as an array named temp and we have no reference for what values were in them prior to this for loop

Comment: `ceil(l1/2.0);` -- Why are you calling floating point functions like `ceil` and using floating point math in a program that has nothing to do with floating point calculations?

Comment: he's dividing a size of something by 2.0 to get left half and right half im guessing... and if total size is odd number will give float result... so ceil to always round up...

Comment: have updated the code. Sorry for imcomplete reference.

Comment: "the bounds" do you refer to `0` and `ceil(l1/2.0)` ?

Comment: i have added explain please statement infront of the two lines which i dont understand please help

Comment: not sure about others, but I tend to ignore comments in code completely. Imho the question would be more clear if you formulated a concrete question (not just "can you please explain?") something like "why is the code using `i + l2` ? I know that `i` is ... and `l2` is ..., but why add the two?" (I just made something up to illustrate what i mean ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 i want to understand what does (j<i || j>=i+l2) do ?

Comment: @DynasticSponge -- Yes, but there is no need for floating point calls for a question that is obviously one of some string manipulation.  You risk round-off error by using such functions, as many other new programmers discover -- things like using `pow`  when all that is required is multiplying by 10.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- perhaps.. but he's trying to get half the length of a string.  If that string has odd length and he divides by integer 2, then it will round down.. not up.  I think his use case is specific enough that he'll never have to worry about precision errors.  Its integer divided by 2.0... so will always result in whole number or float of x.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Palindrome... same backwards as forwards...
The first part of your code overlays s2 on top of characters in s1 starting at some position: i.
the string temp is the first i characters of s1, then all of s2, then whatever characters remain in s1 that werent covered up.  The length of temp should be the length of s1.

In the j loop, you are iterating on 0 to half the size of s1 rounding up.

Your first 'please explain' is looking to see if the index j in the string temp falls on a character that was part of s1 (whether before the s2 characters or after them).  It also looks to see if the character in temp at index j matches its spot on the flip side (ie is that character and its mirror already equal as they would have to be in a palindrome).  If is part of s1, but not a match, you have a cost.

Your second 'please explain' looks at the back half of the temp string... it looks to see if the character at the mirror position to j in the string temp falls on a character that was part of s1 and again looks to see if the character in that position matches its flip... if not, there's a cost.

You're basically looking at the characters in the temp string starting at the ends of the string and working towards the middle.  So you look at the first character first.  If the character is from s1, it can be switched to be whatever the last character is. So you just increment cost.  Then you look at last character in temp.  If it is from s1, then it can be switched to be whatever the first character is. So you just increment cost.  Now increment j, so you're looking at 2nd char and 2nd to last char, increment j again you're looking at 3rd char and 3rd to last char. etc etc....

If at any point you cant swap the char at the front and you cant swap the char at the back.. then if they don't already match, its impossible to have a palindrome.